# Visual Studio 2017 Community does not install

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsinstaller

When installing VS 2017 community on a new windows 10 computer the installer does not download the files. It gets stuck. Other programs such as Visual Studio Code and SQL Server management studio installed properly.
Here is the screenshot.I have tried everything from clean installation to restarting the PC and nothing seems to work so far.
[image]

Comment: do you have an anti virus software that could be interfering with the install/download process?

Comment: No, just the windows defender. It is a new windows 10 64 bit installation.

Comment: try to download an iso file of visual studio, then install like that. Not sure what could be causing your issue. have you tried simple network troubleshooting? restarting your connection hardware etc

Answer (score 0):

It could be a big package. Just be patient for a while.

Comment: Waited one hour and nothing. Even if the speed starts at 3Mb/sec it still gets stuck and nothing happens.